# SSRS Sum Values Based on Earliest Date

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to sum a net balance based on the earliest date in an SSRS report.  In this case there are only 2 dates, but there can be more dates not more than 7 days.

**Here's a sample of my data:**

[image]

**Here's what I'm trying to get with the earliest date of 10/26/15:**

[image]

I've tried the following code, but not able to get this to work:

```
    =Sum(IIf(DateDiff("d",Fields!SettleFullDate.Value,today())>=7 
and DateDiff("d", Fields!SettleFullDate.Value, today())<7
and Fields!SETTLEBALANCE.Value>0), Fields!SETTLEBALANCE.Value, 0)
```

**Update:**  I tried the code below and keep getting an error on the report.  Could it be that I need to change the date field to an integer?
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: For clarity, are you trying to Sum the earliest date in the returned dataset against the sum of the latest date?

Comment: No, the users will have the ability to pull the report to view historical data.  In this case, they could pull the report back several months or even years.  I just noticed why your asking the question because I used 'today()' in my expression.  How would I write the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare the sum of values of two dates, the maximum and minimum in a set you can use the following equation

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!myDate.Value = Max(Fields!myDate.Value), Fields!myVal.Value, 0))
-Sum(iif(Fields!myDate.Value = MIN(Fields!myDate.Value), Fields!myVal.Value, 0))
```

This Sums all the values that match the maximum date in the dataset together, and sums all the values that match the minimum date in the dataset together, and takes one from the other.

It is irrespective of which dates you ask to be received, the above approach will work only against the records that you return to SSRS.  So if you have a  filter (WHERE clause) to return records between Date1 and Date2 this will still apply *(Note - don't actually use 'Between' in the query)*

Rather than using the maximum and minimum dates as listed here, you could also calculate a date similar to your original approach using

```
dateadd("d", -7, Fields!MySpecificDate.Value)
```

And insert that to the expression above.

Hopefully this is what you require - if not please let me know.

Comment: I'm not able to get this expression to work.  All I get is an #Error on my report.  I updated my post.

Comment: Can you check the max and min dates are calculated correctly by pulling them out into their own expressions. If so, I would the do the same for each of the sumifs. In general trying to break it apart to find out where the error is. The calculation itself looks right, but it *might* depend on the underlying data

Comment: By themselves, the min/max expression only pulls back a 'true' value for all the dates.  '=Fields!SettleFullDate.Value = max(Fields!SettleFullDate.Value)'  or '=Fields!SettleFullDate.Value = min(Fields!SettleFullDate.Value).  This expression doesn't populate a date value.

Comment: That because you are performing a comparison.  What does =Max(fields!settlefulldate.value) and the corresponding min value equal. Are they your minimum and maximum dates?

Comment: I had to do the following within my query in sql to get this to work right within SSRS.   'groupdate = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, SettleFullDate), 0)
,       minNetAmount = MIN(NetAmount) OVER ( PARTITION BY acctnbr, settlefulldate )
,       maxNetAmount = MAX(NetAmount) OVER ( PARTITION BY acctnbr, settlefulldate )
,       sumNetAmount = SUM(NetAmount) OVER ( PARTITION BY acctnbr, settlefulldate )
,  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AcctNbr ORDER BY acctnbr, settlefulldate)'....then 'DIFF = CTE.maxNetAmount - CTE.minNetAmount'.   Thanks for your help.  I'll mark as answered.