# Finding difference at group level

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have 3 months of AR data. From SQL I am populating details records for 3 months. In SSRS I am grouping the totals by month and showing only group summary. I want to calculate the variance by difference between current month and previous month. Please see the attached output file.

[image]

Could anyone help me on finding the variance at group level. How do I calculate the difference by using previous function?

Is there any way to find individual group sum of the particular field like this one

```
Sum(Fields!Current.Value, "DataSet1")
```

Comment: In that case you want to calculate the variance for `Total` column between Nov and Oct?

Comment: Is this not the same problem as posed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026259/ssrs-sum-values-based-on-earliest-date/34026614#34026614 just for months rather than specific dates?  Have you tried comparing the sum of if statements?

Comment: I want to calculate the variance for all columns for Nov and Oct row

Comment: @Jonnus,I want only the summary of individual columns for each month in  SSRS. Is there way to get the records for each month from the grouping of the dataset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
=Sum(iif(month(Fields!myDate.Value) = month(Max(Fields!myDate.Value)), Fields!myVal.Value, 0)) 
-Sum(iif(month(Fields!myDate.Value) = month(dateadd("M", -1, max(Fields!myDate.Value))), Fields!myVal.Value, 0))
```

Where myDate is the date used to group the months on, and myVal is the specific data for the column

**UPDATE**

Using this dataset

```
EOM          myValue
09/30/2015   2
10/31/2015   6
11/30/2015   19
```

Gives this basic report

[image]

You can then use this formula (based on the original one in the original answer above) to determine the difference between the last and the penultimate row

```
=Sum(
    iif(month(CDate(Fields!EOM.Value)) = month(Max(Fields!EOM.Value)),   
        Fields!myValue.Value, 
        0)
    ) 
 -Sum(iif(month(CDate(Fields!EOM.Value)) = month(dateadd("M", -1, max(CDate(Fields!EOM.Value)))), 
        Fields!myValue.Value, 
        0)
    )
```

Then place this in the footer of the tablix as shown

[image]

This shows the difference between the two rows

[image]

Is this the behaviour you require?  If not please clarify further in the original question as an update/edit.

Comment: Thank you! This report is calculating the total invoice amount for  30,60,90..days based on the difference between given date and invoice billed date. In SQL  select,  I am passing 3 EOM dates to find the totals individually and using union all to bind together.  Date condition I can not use because it may be billed prior months than the max date I have given. It is not working for me. Is there way using ReportItems collection to get group summary data? If I directly find from the group column itself then, it will help me to find some other calculations.

Comment: I don't understand. What is your source data and what do you want the report to show?

Comment: With the use of CTE,  I am getting 3 rows in SQL. Instead of passing details row, I am passing  only 3 rows to SSRS. No need of grouping at SSRS side. Fields are same as above. Could you help me to find differences  in last row and prev row for all the columns based on this? TIA

Comment: Thank you very much, I can not express my thanks on this one. I just updated Fields!myValue.Value to cDbl(Fields!myValue.Value) for data type mismatch error. I did not figure it out this error yesterday. This works as expected. Marked as Answer.

Comment: @Renu Excellent - I'm glad we got there in the end